# Mavericks mail.app to/cc header detail white color

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, color

my mail.app suddenly stopped showing me to/cc header detail in all emails. I had a better look at it and those headers are there, but are displayed in white color. Details on image:

[image: Missing headers]

I tried changing color via Command + T, but it seems that it only changes email color, not text color. I also tried to remove file from ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist and restarting the Mail.app, but that didn't help either.

How should I restore to the default behaviour?

Comment: Only in "all mails" or other places?

Comment: Other places as well, practically every email has those fields "blank"

Comment: Did you somehow modify any of the system fonts ?

Comment: Open Font-Book.app and under file run restore standard fonts.

Answer (score 1):

In case the system fonts got modified somehow I recommend to reset them.

To do this open the app called Font-book and under the File tab click on the "Restore standard Fonts".  Then, reboot the computer.

That should fix your problem.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, although restoring to standard font didn't helped. I also quit and relaunched the mail.app, restart the computer, but still no luck. any other tip you can share?

Comment: I am having the same difficulties. Has any one found the solution?

Comment: nevermind, "restore Standard Fonts" and a reboot worked.